# What's the correct way to create form handling edit action

Tags: laravel, routes

I try to send some from form to edit it.

I tried to use different ways to achieve this result. None of them worked.

```
<form method= "GET" action="{{route('edit', $contact->id)}}" name="edit">
                ...etc
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and

```
<form method= "GET" action="/{{$contact->id}}/edit" name="edit">
                ...etc
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I use standard routing:

```
Route::resource('/', 'ContactController');
```

It creates URL's ending with question marks (consequence of using GET), but even if I manually delete it from URL, it still doesn't work and shows 404 page. What's wrong with it? What's the correct way to do that?

Edit:
[image: Route list]

Comment: The first argument to `Route::resource` should be a resource "name", ex: `Route::resource('contact', 'ContactController')`  ... run `php artisan route:list` to see what routes are created ... without a resource name, there is nothing to name the placeholder by

Comment: If you run the terminal command `php artisan route:list`, you'll see all your available routes. Your `<form>` element's `method` and `action` need to match one of those routes. You can use the `url()` or `route()` helpers to determine the `action`, and make sure the `method` matches.

Comment: Well, it matches, doesn't it?

Comment: `{{$contact->id}}/edit` does not match `{}/edit`; it's missing a URL parameter. Generally you'd see `{contact}/edit`. You definitely need to pass a name to your resource routes.

Comment: I apologize, Tim. I'm still not entirely sure what you mean. What's the valid form of `action` attribute? (once again sorry, I really am a newbie)

Comment: That's ok! I don't think the action is the issue; there's a number of ways to generate that, and `{{ $contact->id }}/edit` "works" (there are different ways to do this, such as using the `route()` or `url()` helpers), but `{}/edit` doesn't seem like a valid route, and as the answer suggests below, it's because you're missing the first param of `Route::resource()`; check the answers and see if they help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument for `Route::resource` is the name for the resource, which also ends up being part of the path:

```
Route::resource('contact', 'ContactController');
```

Then you can use your route helper:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('contact.update', ['contact' => $contact->id]) }}">
@method('PUT')
```

The 'edit' route is for showing the edit form not processing. The 'update' route is for doing the update, where the edit form posts to.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will generate a route based on your web.php route definiitions

`{{ action('ContactController@edit', $contact)}}`

So just drop that in to your form declaration

```
<form method= "POST" action="{{ action('ContactController@edit', $contact)}}" name="edit">
@method('PATCH')
```

Note that I changed the method to post and added the @method view helper to generate a hidden field with the correct method to use. You cannot use a get route to update a model unless you define that route manually but I would not recommend it, stick to the correct REST verbs
You also need to use